# Highcharts positioning of datalabel for a specific slice

Tags: highcharts

I am not able to change the position of a datalabel of a specific slice in a pie chart.

For example, if the data is :

```
data : [ 
       ['Apples', 29.428125119061225],
         {
           name: 'Oranges', 
           y : 70.57187488093878, 
           dataLabels : { distance : -90}  
         }
       ]
```

The above `distance` has no effect on the slice.

In fact, looks like the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-distance/) given for above in the Highchart [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) also doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Looks like it was indeed a bug (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1174) which got fixed a week ago! Just need to wait for the next release.

Comment: have a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35708201/3898339)

Comment: Thanks @Deep3015. Its an interesting workaround to have each slice as its own series and adjust the slice properties that way. Hopefully, the recent fix of the bug above will also make it easier.

Comment: It will! Release 5.0.11 should be ready this week ;)

Comment: @PawełFus! You guys are super heroes - thanks so much

Comment: And it's released :) Let me know how it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [known bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1174) and as mentioned by @PawelFus, fixed in v5.0.11