# Use variable radius from HighCharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to use a variable radius pie : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variable-radius-pie from HighCharts.

Please note that I'm using HighCharts via an angular module : [angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts).

I'm working with Angular 8.

In `ngOnInit()` I fill my HighCharts object.

```
this.pie = new Chart({
      chart: {
        type: 'variablepie',
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Variable radius',
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'transactions',
        minPointSize: 10,
        zMin: 0,
        type: 'variablepie',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [
         {name: "Forwarding", y: 379, z: 379}
         {name: "Processing", y: 883, z: 883}
         {name: "Processed", y: 487, z: 487}
         {name: "Error", y: 986, z: 986}
         {name: "Incomes", y: 43, z: 43}
        ]
    }],
});
```

I also include in `app.module.ts` :

```
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: () => [ more, exporting ]
    }
  ]
})
```

With this, I'm getting an [error 17](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17) into the console.

This tell me I have to import a script because `variable radius` pie need a specific script.

I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414875/can-i-assign-a-different-radius-for-each-pie-slice-using-highcharts/35416334) that I have to import this script : `(<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variable-pie.js"></script>`

I tried to put it in:

- `index.html` : It didn't work
- the file I'm using HighCharts : It didn't work

Just want to know if some of you found a solution for this ?

**EDIT 1**

I change my code like this.
`myModule.module.ts` :

```
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    HighchartsChartModule,
    ...
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

`myComponent.component.ts` :

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

 Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    }]
 };
```

`mycomponent.component.html` :

```
<highcharts-chart style="width: 100%; display: block"
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions">
</highcharts-chart>
```

I'm getting this error : Can't bind to 'Highcharts' since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.

Comment: Do you use the official highcharts-angular wrapper? What kind of Version do u use? You could use importing the modules like so: ```import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'```  then you do  ```import Pie from 'highcharts/modules/variable-pie' ``` afterwards you do the following pass Highcharts as parameter to Variable Pie like so ```Pie(Highcharts)```regards

Comment: I suggest to use this Highcharts wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: please check you have type files....npm install --save @types/highcharts

Comment: @sagat No, I'm using an angular module : [angular-highCharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts). I edited my post to give more informations.

The fact is that this module is already use to several point of the project, So unfortunately I can't switch to HighCharts official use :/

I didn't have @types/highcharts. But when I added it, it make my project really slow.

Comment: I understand. The package I posted is the Official Angular Wrapper by highcharts, they deliver support for that. Thats y I suggested to go by that lib. For me it worked great and they answered any question really fast at the support. DSid u try my approach?

Comment: @sagat Yes I tried it. Always the same error. Maybe I will switch on Official HighCharts, then I will change every time we use highChart.

Comment: hello? Can u pls give feedback?

Comment: **I FOUND THE SOLUTION** : As @sagat said, I didn't import `HighchartsChartModule` at the good place. I had to put it in the `shared.module.ts`, at the same place you declare the component which use HighchartsChart.
Really thank you to all people who helped me, especially @sagat !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mate do this in your component.ts:**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HPie from 'highcharts/modules/variable-pie';

HPie(Highcharts);
```

**In the module u just import this:**

```
...
import {HighchartsChartModule} from 'highcharts-angular';
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        HighchartsChartModule <--- Import HighchartsModule
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
      ... <--- somewhere here the component in which u want to use the highcharts component
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: []
})
```

**In your component.ts:**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...
 // Chartstuff
    Highcharts = Highcharts;
    chart: Highcharts.Chart;
    updateFlag: boolean;
    chartOptions;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.initChart(data: any) <--- anyData from http call
}

initChart(yourData: any) {


this.chartOptions = {
    chart: {
    type: 'variablepie'
},
accessibility: {
    description: 'A variable radius pie chart'
},
title: {
    text: 'Countries compared by population density and total area.'
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.name}</b><br/>' +
        'Area (square km): <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' +
        'Population density (people per square km): <b>{point.z}</b><br/>'
},
series: [{
    minPointSize: 10,
    innerSize: '20%',
    zMin: 0,
    name: 'countries',
    data: [{
        name: 'Spain',
        y: 505370,
        z: 92.9
    }, {
        name: 'France',
        y: 551500,
        z: 118.7
    }, {
        name: 'Poland',
        y: 312685,
        z: 124.6
    }, {
        name: 'Czech Republic',
        y: 78867,
        z: 137.5
    }, {
        name: 'Italy',
        y: 301340,
        z: 201.8
    }, {
        name: 'Switzerland',
        y: 41277,
        z: 214.5
    }, {
        name: 'Germany',
        y: 357022,
        z: 235.6
    }]
}]
  }
            ...
}
```

**And in ur component.html file use their highcharts-chart component:**

```
<highcharts-chart style="width: 100%; display: block" [Highcharts]="Highcharts"     
    [options]="chartOptions" [runOutsideAngular]="true" [oneToOne]="true"
    (chartInstance)="logChartInstance($event)">
```

This works fine for me in order to import the needed functionality.
See the full documentation here: [highcharts-angular-docs](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)

And for loading modules and plugins go here: [highcharts-angular-modules](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module)

**EDIT:**

**Here is a working example with angular on stackblitz:** [variable-pie-angular-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-variable-pie-demo-angular)

regards

Comment: I tried it ! And really thank you for your help but it didn't work. I follow the doc, and the errors on GitHub, but it didn't work. I4m getting this error : `Can't bind to 'Highcharts' since it isn't a known property of 'highcharts-chart'.`. It's weird because highCharts module is imported at the good place. I verify several times, I don't think I forgrotten something. I edited my post :)

Comment: Yes did u npm install highcharts as well? What is in ur package.json+

Comment: Yes, I have several : `angular-highcharts`, `highcharts` and `highcharts-angular`

Comment: okay delete angular highcharts. In which module do u import HicghchartsChartModule? Hopefully in the same module where u registered the component u want to use hicghcharts in

Comment: I added a workinf stackblitz to the answer. Please check it out. This definetly works. Read my answer and the Stackblitz carefully pls. regards

Comment: I can't delete `angulat=r-highcharts` module because all my project use this module. I'm seeing your stackblitz and there's no difference with my code. So maybe it's linked to `angular-highcharts` :/ I will start another project, as soon as I will find the solution I will post it. Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: As I see your code where you import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'; you forgot to do this --> ```import HPie from 'highcharts/modules/variable-pie';
HPie(Highcharts);``` <-- as this is importing the needed module for variable pie

Comment: **I FOUND THE SOLUTION** : As I said on my post, I found the solution, thanks to you ! I just put the `import HighCharts` on the wrong module ...

Comment: happy to hear, somewhere on the comments I tried to make u aware of that :) Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, I know ‍♂️ Thanks again !!